# Сравнение массивов (javascript , jquery )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер, есть два массива, нужно сделать один массив, но чтобы значения не совпадали, т.е. в массивах может быть два значения "1000362636:Вася", но в общем это не должно повторяться.
Получается массив может быть с цифрами и со словами, т.е. он не должен быть индексный, а ассоционный, т.е. слова. Понимаете?

Написал такую формулу.

```
var a1=[1000362636:Вася, 1000362636:Вася,1000657019:Петя, 1000777535:Коля];
var a2=[1000362636:Вася, 1000362636:Вася, 1087350196:Вика, 1079746208:Зина];

var Arr1_2=[]; //массив с общими цифрами 

//сравнение массивов, перечисляем массив a1
$.each(a1,function(index1,value1){  

     //перечисляем массив aу
      $.each(a2,function(index2,value2){    

         //ЕСЛИ ЕСТЬ СОВПАДЕНИЕ СОДАЕМ ЕГО В  ОБЩЕМ МАССИВЕ
         if(value1.toString()==value2.toString()){  
            Arr1_2[value2.toString()*1]='';     
            }          
    })

});
```

При этом хочу сразу заметить, конструкция:

```
Arr1_2.push(value2.toString());
```

только добавляет, т.е. могут быть дубли в массиве Arr1_2,т.к. индексы у них будут разные. К сожалению, конструкция

```
Arr1_2[value2.toString()*1]='';
```

тоже не позволяет убрать дубли.
Что делать, помогите, пожалуйста.
Как добавлять значения, и отсекать если это значение у же есть в массиве?

```
$.each(Arr1_2,function(index,value){
      console.log('Индекс: ' + index.toString() + '; Значение: ' +   value.toString());
});
```

Comment: А если в одном из массивов есть одинаковые элементы - с ними что? Какой результат ожидается для приведенных данных?

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, синтаксически правильное определение входных данных и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что делать

Внятно, с примерами, описать, чего Вы хотите добиться.

```js
var a1=[1000362636,1000362636,"петя123",1000777535];
var a2=[1000362636,1000362636,1087350196,"петя123"];

var result = [];

function addUnique(src, dst) {
  for(var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    if (dst.indexOf(src[i]) == -1)
      result.push(src[i]);
  }
}

addUnique(a1, result);
addUnique(a2, result);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не конец) А если значения могут быть не цифры, а названия "петя123", "катя2232"? как потом вывести последовательно весь массив?

Comment: @Максим147 Не понял вопроса. А как Вы выводите массив с "цифрами"? Также и с "названиями".

Comment: исправил, получается массив может быть с цифрами и со словами, т.е. он не должен быть индексный, а ассоционный. Понимаете?

Comment: @Максим147 Пока только догадываюсь :). То, что Вы исправили в вопросе, - не javascript. Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, правильное определение входных данных и ожидаемый результат.